# Joomla 4 - Profile Plugin

Tags: joomla-4.x

I need a custom profile plugin, so I copied the default user profile, renamed some folders/files, and installed it.  It installs as if fine and I can activate it, but the fields don't actually display in the registration form.  I activate the default user profile, and it does display the fields. I feel like that means it's not pulling the customprofile.xml file, but I can't tell why not.

**File Structure:**

[image: file structure]

**customprofile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="plugin" group="user" method="upgrade">
    <name>PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE</name>
    <author>QTown</author>
    <creationDate>2022-12</creationDate>
    <copyright></copyright>
    <license>GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt</license>
    <authorEmail>myemail@here.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>www.mysite.org</authorUrl>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <description>PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_XML_DESCRIPTION</description>
    <namespace path="src">Qtown\Plugin\User\Customprofile</namespace>
    <files>
        <filename plugin="customprofile">customprofile.php</filename>
        <folder>forms</folder>
        <folder>src</folder>
    </files>
    <languages>
        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/plg_user_customprofile.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">language/en-GB/plg_user_customprofile.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic" addfieldprefix="Joomla\Component\Content\Administrator\Field">
                <field
                    name="register-require-user"
                    type="spacer"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_NAME_REGISTER_REQUIRE_USER"
                    class="text"
                />

                <field
                    name="register-require_address1"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_ADDRESS1_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="register-require_address2"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_ADDRESS2_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="register-require_city"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_CITY_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="register-require_region"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_REGION_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="register-require_country"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_COUNTRY_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="register-require_postal_code"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_POSTAL_CODE_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="register-require_phone"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_PHONE_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="register-require_website"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_WEB_SITE_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="register-require_favoritebook"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_FAVORITE_BOOK_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="register-require_aboutme"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_ABOUT_ME_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="register-require_tos"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_TOS_LABEL"
                    default="0"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="register_tos_article"
                    type="modal_article"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_TOS_ARTICLE_LABEL"
                    select="true"
                    new="true"
                    edit="true"
                    clear="true"
                    filter="integer"
                />

                <field
                    name="register-require_dob"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_DOB_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="spacer1"
                    type="spacer"
                    hr="true"
                />

                <field
                    name="profile-require-user"
                    type="spacer"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_NAME_PROFILE_REQUIRE_USER"
                    class="text"
                />

                <field
                    name="profile-require_address1"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_ADDRESS1_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="profile-require_address2"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_ADDRESS2_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="profile-require_city"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_CITY_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="profile-require_region"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_REGION_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="profile-require_country"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_COUNTRY_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="profile-require_postal_code"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_POSTAL_CODE_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="profile-require_phone"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_PHONE_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="profile-require_website"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_WEB_SITE_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="profile-require_favoritebook"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_FAVORITE_BOOK_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="profile-require_aboutme"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_ABOUT_ME_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>

                <field
                    name="profile-require_dob"
                    type="list"
                    label="PLG_CUSTOM_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_DOB_LABEL"
                    default="1"
                    filter="integer"
                    validate="options"
                    >
                    <option value="2">JOPTION_REQUIRED</option>
                    <option value="1">JOPTION_OPTIONAL</option>
                    <option value="0">JDISABLED</option>
                </field>
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

**customprofile.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * @package     Joomla.Plugin
 * @subpackage  User.profile
 *
 * @copyright   (C) 2009 Open Source Matters, Inc. <https://www.joomla.org>
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt

 * @phpcs:disable PSR1.Classes.ClassDeclaration.MissingNamespace
 */

use Joomla\CMS\Date\Date;
use Joomla\CMS\Form\Form;
use Joomla\CMS\Form\FormHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;
use Joomla\CMS\String\PunycodeHelper;
use Joomla\Database\ParameterType;
use Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper;

// phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
\defined('_JEXEC') or die;
// phpcs:enable PSR1.Files.SideEffects

/**
 * An example custom profile plugin.
 *
 * @since  1.6
 */
class PlgUserCustomProfile extends CMSPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var    \Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication
     *
     * @since  4.0.0
     */
    protected $app;

    /**
     * @var    \Joomla\Database\DatabaseDriver
     *
     * @since  4.0.0
     */
    protected $db;

    /**
     * Load the language file on instantiation.
     *
     * @var    boolean
     *
     * @since  3.1
     */
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

    /**
     * Date of birth.
     *
     * @var    string
     *
     * @since  3.1
     */
    private $date = '';

    /**
     * Runs on content preparation
     *
     * @param   string  $context  The context for the data
     * @param   object  $data     An object containing the data for the form.
     *
     * @return  boolean
     *
     * @since   1.6
     */
    public function onContentPrepareData($context, $data)
    {
        // Check we are manipulating a valid form.
        if (!in_array($context, ['com_users.profile', 'com_users.user', 'com_users.registration'])) {
            return true;
        }

        if (is_object($data)) {
            $userId = $data->id ?? 0;

            if (!isset($data->profile) && $userId > 0) {
                // Load the profile data from the database.
                $db    = $this->db;
                $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                    ->select(
                        [
                            $db->quoteName('profile_key'),
                            $db->quoteName('profile_value'),
                        ]
                    )
                    ->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
                    ->where($db->quoteName('user_id') . ' = :userid')
                    ->where($db->quoteName('profile_key') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('profile.%'))
                    ->order($db->quoteName('ordering'))
                    ->bind(':userid', $userId, ParameterType::INTEGER);

                $db->setQuery($query);
                $results = $db->loadRowList();

                // Merge the profile data.
                $data->profile = [];

                foreach ($results as $v) {
                    $k = str_replace('profile.', '', $v[0]);
                    $data->profile[$k] = json_decode($v[1], true);

                    if ($data->profile[$k] === null) {
                        $data->profile[$k] = $v[1];
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!HTMLHelper::isRegistered('users.url')) {
                HTMLHelper::register('users.url', [__CLASS__, 'url']);
            }

            if (!HTMLHelper::isRegistered('users.calendar')) {
                HTMLHelper::register('users.calendar', [__CLASS__, 'calendar']);
            }

            if (!HTMLHelper::isRegistered('users.tos')) {
                HTMLHelper::register('users.tos', [__CLASS__, 'tos']);
            }

            if (!HTMLHelper::isRegistered('users.dob')) {
                HTMLHelper::register('users.dob', [__CLASS__, 'dob']);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an anchor tag generated from a given value
     *
     * @param   string  $value  URL to use
     *
     * @return  mixed|string
     */
    public static function url($value)
    {
        if (empty($value)) {
            return HTMLHelper::_('users.value', $value);
        } else {
            // Convert website URL to utf8 for display
            $value = PunycodeHelper::urlToUTF8(htmlspecialchars($value));

            if (strpos($value, 'http') === 0) {
                return '<a href="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>';
            } else {
                return '<a href="http://' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>';
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns html markup showing a date picker
     *
     * @param   string  $value  valid date string
     *
     * @return  mixed
     */
    public static function calendar($value)
    {
        if (empty($value)) {
            return HTMLHelper::_('users.value', $value);
        } else {
            return HTMLHelper::_('date', $value, null, null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the date of birth formatted and calculated using server timezone.
     *
     * @param   string  $value  valid date string
     *
     * @return  mixed
     */
    public static function dob($value)
    {
        if (!$value) {
            return '';
        }

        return HTMLHelper::_('date', $value, Text::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC1'), false);
    }

    /**
     * Return the translated strings yes or no depending on the value
     *
     * @param   boolean  $value  input value
     *
     * @return  string
     */
    public static function tos($value)
    {
        if ($value) {
            return Text::_('JYES');
        } else {
            return Text::_('JNO');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds additional fields to the user editing form
     *
     * @param   Form   $form  The form to be altered.
     * @param   mixed  $data  The associated data for the form.
     *
     * @return  boolean
     *
     * @since   1.6
     */
    public function onContentPrepareForm(Form $form, $data)
    {
        // Check we are manipulating a valid form.
        $name = $form->getName();

        if (!in_array($name, ['com_users.user', 'com_users.profile', 'com_users.registration'])) {
            return true;
        }

        // Add the registration fields to the form.
        FormHelper::addFieldPrefix('Joomla\\Plugin\\User\\Profile\\Field');
        FormHelper::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');
        $form->loadFile('profile');

        $fields = [
            'address1',
            'address2',
            'city',
            'region',
            'country',
            'postal_code',
            'phone',
            'website',
            'favoritebook',
            'aboutme',
            'dob',
            'tos',
        ];

        $tosArticle = $this->params->get('register_tos_article');
        $tosEnabled = $this->params->get('register-require_tos', 0);

        // We need to be in the registration form and field needs to be enabled
        if ($name !== 'com_users.registration' || !$tosEnabled) {
            // We only want the TOS in the registration form
            $form->removeField('tos', 'profile');
        } else {
            // Push the TOS article ID into the TOS field.
            $form->setFieldAttribute('tos', 'article', $tosArticle, 'profile');
        }

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            // Case using the users manager in admin
            if ($name === 'com_users.user') {
                // Toggle whether the field is required.
                if ($this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field, 1) > 0) {
                    $form->setFieldAttribute($field, 'required', ($this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field) == 2) ? 'required' : '', 'profile');
                } elseif (
                    // Remove the field if it is disabled in registration and profile
                    $this->params->get('register-require_' . $field, 1) == 0
                    && $this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field, 1) == 0
                ) {
                    $form->removeField($field, 'profile');
                }
            } elseif ($name === 'com_users.registration') {
                // Case registration
                // Toggle whether the field is required.
                if ($this->params->get('register-require_' . $field, 1) > 0) {
                    $form->setFieldAttribute($field, 'required', ($this->params->get('register-require_' . $field) == 2) ? 'required' : '', 'profile');
                } else {
                    $form->removeField($field, 'profile');
                }
            } elseif ($name === 'com_users.profile') {
                // Case profile in site or admin
                // Toggle whether the field is required.
                if ($this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field, 1) > 0) {
                    $form->setFieldAttribute($field, 'required', ($this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field) == 2) ? 'required' : '', 'profile');
                } else {
                    $form->removeField($field, 'profile');
                }
            }
        }

        // Drop the profile form entirely if there aren't any fields to display.
        $remainingfields = $form->getGroup('profile');

        if (!count($remainingfields)) {
            $form->removeGroup('profile');
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Method is called before user data is stored in the database
     *
     * @param   array    $user   Holds the old user data.
     * @param   boolean  $isnew  True if a new user is stored.
     * @param   array    $data   Holds the new user data.
     *
     * @return  boolean
     *
     * @since   3.1
     * @throws  InvalidArgumentException on invalid date.
     */
    public function onUserBeforeSave($user, $isnew, $data)
    {
        // Check that the date is valid.
        if (!empty($data['profile']['dob'])) {
            try {
                $date = new Date($data['profile']['dob']);
                $this->date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Throw an exception if date is not valid.
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(Text::_('PLG_USER_PROFILE_ERROR_INVALID_DOB'));
            }

            if (Date::getInstance('now') < $date) {
                // Throw an exception if dob is greater than now.
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(Text::_('PLG_USER_PROFILE_ERROR_INVALID_DOB_FUTURE_DATE'));
            }
        }

        // Check that the tos is checked if required ie only in registration from frontend.
        $task       = $this->app->input->getCmd('task');
        $option     = $this->app->input->getCmd('option');
        $tosEnabled = ($this->params->get('register-require_tos', 0) == 2);

        // Check that the tos is checked.
        if ($task === 'register' && $tosEnabled && $option === 'com_users' && !$data['profile']['tos']) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(Text::_('PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_TOS_DESC_SITE'));
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Saves user profile data
     *
     * @param   array    $data    entered user data
     * @param   boolean  $isNew   true if this is a new user
     * @param   boolean  $result  true if saving the user worked
     * @param   string   $error   error message
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function onUserAfterSave($data, $isNew, $result, $error): void
    {
        $userId = ArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'id', 0, 'int');

        if ($userId && $result && isset($data['profile']) && count($data['profile'])) {
            $db = $this->db;

            // Sanitize the date
            if (!empty($data['profile']['dob'])) {
                $data['profile']['dob'] = $this->date;
            }

            $keys = array_keys($data['profile']);

            foreach ($keys as &$key) {
                $key = 'profile.' . $key;
            }

            $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->delete($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
                ->where($db->quoteName('user_id') . ' = :userid')
                ->whereIn($db->quoteName('profile_key'), $keys, ParameterType::STRING)
                ->bind(':userid', $userId, ParameterType::INTEGER);
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->execute();

            $query->clear()
                ->select($db->quoteName('ordering'))
                ->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
                ->where($db->quoteName('user_id') . ' = :userid')
                ->bind(':userid', $userId, ParameterType::INTEGER);
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $usedOrdering = $db->loadColumn();

            $order = 1;
            $query->clear()
                ->insert($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'));

            foreach ($data['profile'] as $k => $v) {
                while (in_array($order, $usedOrdering)) {
                    $order++;
                }

                $query->values(
                    implode(
                        ',',
                        $query->bindArray(
                            [
                                $userId,
                                'profile.' . $k,
                                json_encode($v),
                                $order++,
                            ],
                            [
                                ParameterType::INTEGER,
                                ParameterType::STRING,
                                ParameterType::STRING,
                                ParameterType::INTEGER,
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                );
            }

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->execute();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove all user profile information for the given user ID
     *
     * Method is called after user data is deleted from the database
     *
     * @param   array    $user     Holds the user data
     * @param   boolean  $success  True if user was successfully stored in the database
     * @param   string   $msg      Message
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function onUserAfterDelete($user, $success, $msg): void
    {
        if (!$success) {
            return;
        }

        $userId = ArrayHelper::getValue($user, 'id', 0, 'int');

        if ($userId) {
            $db = $this->db;
            $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->delete($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
                ->where($db->quoteName('user_id') . ' = :userid')
                ->where($db->quoteName('profile_key') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('profile.%'))
                ->bind(':userid', $userId, ParameterType::INTEGER);

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the custom fields you have set are just a repeat of the standard profile fields?  So I guess I have to ask why?  All my custom profile plugins I've created have been by adding an extension to "profile" such as  PlgUserProfilexxxx and then I replace all reference to profile to be "profilexxxx".  This then provides extra fields in the #__user_profiles table.

Comment: The idea is to add new fields, and this is just the start to make sure I understand how the plugin should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The profile key in the database should be the same as your plugin name, ie PlgUserCustomProfile means that your key field should be like

```
foreach ($data['customprofile'] as $k => $v)
```

So perhaps try this:

```
    <?php

/**
 * @package     Joomla.Plugin
 * @subpackage  User.customprofile
 *
 * @copyright   (C) 2009 Open Source Matters, Inc. <https://www.joomla.org>
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt

 * @phpcs:disable PSR1.Classes.ClassDeclaration.MissingNamespace
 */

use Joomla\CMS\Date\Date;
use Joomla\CMS\Form\Form;
use Joomla\CMS\Form\FormHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;
use Joomla\CMS\String\PunycodeHelper;
use Joomla\Database\ParameterType;
use Joomla\Utilities\ArrayHelper;

// phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects
\defined('_JEXEC') or die;
// phpcs:enable PSR1.Files.SideEffects

/**
 * An example custom customprofile plugin.
 *
 * @since  1.6
 */
class PlgUserCustomProfile extends CMSPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var    \Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication
     *
     * @since  4.0.0
     */
    protected $app;

    /**
     * @var    \Joomla\Database\DatabaseDriver
     *
     * @since  4.0.0
     */
    protected $db;

    /**
     * Load the language file on instantiation.
     *
     * @var    boolean
     *
     * @since  3.1
     */
    protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

    /**
     * Date of birth.
     *
     * @var    string
     *
     * @since  3.1
     */
    private $date = '';

    /**
     * Runs on content preparation
     *
     * @param   string  $context  The context for the data
     * @param   object  $data     An object containing the data for the form.
     *
     * @return  boolean
     *
     * @since   1.6
     */
    public function onContentPrepareData($context, $data)
    {
        // Check we are manipulating a valid form.
        if (!in_array($context, ['com_users.profile', 'com_users.user', 'com_users.registration'])) {
            return true;
        }

        if (is_object($data)) {
            $userId = $data->id ?? 0;

            if (!isset($data->customprofile) && $userId > 0) {
                // Load the profile data from the database.
                $db    = $this->db;
                $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                    ->select(
                        [
                            $db->quoteName('profile_key'),
                            $db->quoteName('profile_value'),
                        ]
                    )
                    ->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
                    ->where($db->quoteName('user_id') . ' = :userid')
                    ->where($db->quoteName('profile_key') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('customprofile.%'))
                    ->order($db->quoteName('ordering'))
                    ->bind(':userid', $userId, ParameterType::INTEGER);

                $db->setQuery($query);
                $results = $db->loadRowList();

                // Merge the profile data.
                $data->customprofile = [];

                foreach ($results as $v) {
                    $k = str_replace('customprofile.', '', $v[0]);
                    $data->customprofile[$k] = json_decode($v[1], true);

                    if ($data->customprofile[$k] === null) {
                        $data->customprofile[$k] = $v[1];
                    }
                }
            }

            if (!HTMLHelper::isRegistered('users.url')) {
                HTMLHelper::register('users.url', [__CLASS__, 'url']);
            }

            if (!HTMLHelper::isRegistered('users.calendar')) {
                HTMLHelper::register('users.calendar', [__CLASS__, 'calendar']);
            }

            if (!HTMLHelper::isRegistered('users.tos')) {
                HTMLHelper::register('users.tos', [__CLASS__, 'tos']);
            }

            if (!HTMLHelper::isRegistered('users.dob')) {
                HTMLHelper::register('users.dob', [__CLASS__, 'dob']);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an anchor tag generated from a given value
     *
     * @param   string  $value  URL to use
     *
     * @return  mixed|string
     */
    public static function url($value)
    {
        if (empty($value)) {
            return HTMLHelper::_('users.value', $value);
        } else {
            // Convert website URL to utf8 for display
            $value = PunycodeHelper::urlToUTF8(htmlspecialchars($value));

            if (strpos($value, 'http') === 0) {
                return '<a href="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>';
            } else {
                return '<a href="http://' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a>';
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns html markup showing a date picker
     *
     * @param   string  $value  valid date string
     *
     * @return  mixed
     */
    public static function calendar($value)
    {
        if (empty($value)) {
            return HTMLHelper::_('users.value', $value);
        } else {
            return HTMLHelper::_('date', $value, null, null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the date of birth formatted and calculated using server timezone.
     *
     * @param   string  $value  valid date string
     *
     * @return  mixed
     */
    public static function dob($value)
    {
        if (!$value) {
            return '';
        }

        return HTMLHelper::_('date', $value, Text::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC1'), false);
    }

    /**
     * Return the translated strings yes or no depending on the value
     *
     * @param   boolean  $value  input value
     *
     * @return  string
     */
    public static function tos($value)
    {
        if ($value) {
            return Text::_('JYES');
        } else {
            return Text::_('JNO');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds additional fields to the user editing form
     *
     * @param   Form   $form  The form to be altered.
     * @param   mixed  $data  The associated data for the form.
     *
     * @return  boolean
     *
     * @since   1.6
     */
    public function onContentPrepareForm(Form $form, $data)
    {
        // Check we are manipulating a valid form.
        $name = $form->getName();

        if (!in_array($name, ['com_users.user', 'com_users.profile', 'com_users.registration'])) {
            return true;
        }

        // Add the registration fields to the form.
        FormHelper::addFieldPrefix('Joomla\\Plugin\\User\\Profile\\Field');
        FormHelper::addFormPath(__DIR__ . '/forms');
        $form->loadFile('customprofile');

        $fields = [
            'address1',
            'address2',
            'city',
            'region',
            'country',
            'postal_code',
            'phone',
            'website',
            'favoritebook',
            'aboutme',
            'dob',
            'tos',
        ];

        $tosArticle = $this->params->get('register_tos_article');
        $tosEnabled = $this->params->get('register-require_tos', 0);

        // We need to be in the registration form and field needs to be enabled
        if ($name !== 'com_users.registration' || !$tosEnabled) {
            // We only want the TOS in the registration form
            $form->removeField('tos', 'customprofile');
        } else {
            // Push the TOS article ID into the TOS field.
            $form->setFieldAttribute('tos', 'article', $tosArticle, 'customprofile');
        }

        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            // Case using the users manager in admin
            if ($name === 'com_users.user') {
                // Toggle whether the field is required.
                if ($this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field, 1) > 0) {
                    $form->setFieldAttribute($field, 'required', ($this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field) == 2) ? 'required' : '', 'customprofile');
                } elseif (
                    // Remove the field if it is disabled in registration and customprofile
                    $this->params->get('register-require_' . $field, 1) == 0
                    && $this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field, 1) == 0
                ) {
                    $form->removeField($field, 'customprofile');
                }
            } elseif ($name === 'com_users.registration') {
                // Case registration
                // Toggle whether the field is required.
                if ($this->params->get('register-require_' . $field, 1) > 0) {
                    $form->setFieldAttribute($field, 'required', ($this->params->get('register-require_' . $field) == 2) ? 'required' : '', 'customprofile');
                } else {
                    $form->removeField($field, 'customprofile');
                }
            } elseif ($name === 'com_users.profile') {
                // Case profile in site or admin
                // Toggle whether the field is required.
                if ($this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field, 1) > 0) {
                    $form->setFieldAttribute($field, 'required', ($this->params->get('profile-require_' . $field) == 2) ? 'required' : '', 'customprofile');
                } else {
                    $form->removeField($field, 'customprofile');
                }
            }
        }

        // Drop the customprofile form entirely if there aren't any fields to display.
        $remainingfields = $form->getGroup('customprofile');

        if (!count($remainingfields)) {
            $form->removeGroup('customprofile');
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Method is called before user data is stored in the database
     *
     * @param   array    $user   Holds the old user data.
     * @param   boolean  $isnew  True if a new user is stored.
     * @param   array    $data   Holds the new user data.
     *
     * @return  boolean
     *
     * @since   3.1
     * @throws  InvalidArgumentException on invalid date.
     */
    public function onUserBeforeSave($user, $isnew, $data)
    {
        // Check that the date is valid.
        if (!empty($data['customprofile']['dob'])) {
            try {
                $date = new Date($data['customprofile']['dob']);
                $this->date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // Throw an exception if date is not valid.
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(Text::_('PLG_USER_PROFILE_ERROR_INVALID_DOB'));
            }

            if (Date::getInstance('now') < $date) {
                // Throw an exception if dob is greater than now.
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(Text::_('PLG_USER_PROFILE_ERROR_INVALID_DOB_FUTURE_DATE'));
            }
        }

        // Check that the tos is checked if required ie only in registration from frontend.
        $task       = $this->app->input->getCmd('task');
        $option     = $this->app->input->getCmd('option');
        $tosEnabled = ($this->params->get('register-require_tos', 0) == 2);

        // Check that the tos is checked.
        if ($task === 'register' && $tosEnabled && $option === 'com_users' && !$data['customprofile']['tos']) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(Text::_('PLG_USER_PROFILE_FIELD_TOS_DESC_SITE'));
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Saves user customprofile data
     *
     * @param   array    $data    entered user data
     * @param   boolean  $isNew   true if this is a new user
     * @param   boolean  $result  true if saving the user worked
     * @param   string   $error   error message
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function onUserAfterSave($data, $isNew, $result, $error): void
    {
        $userId = ArrayHelper::getValue($data, 'id', 0, 'int');

        if ($userId && $result && isset($data['customprofile']) && count($data['customprofile'])) {
            $db = $this->db;

            // Sanitize the date
            if (!empty($data['customprofile']['dob'])) {
                $data['customprofile']['dob'] = $this->date;
            }

            $keys = array_keys($data['customprofile']);

            foreach ($keys as &$key) {
                $key = 'customprofile.' . $key;
            }

            $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->delete($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
                ->where($db->quoteName('user_id') . ' = :userid')
                ->whereIn($db->quoteName('profile_key'), $keys, ParameterType::STRING)
                ->bind(':userid', $userId, ParameterType::INTEGER);
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->execute();

            $query->clear()
                ->select($db->quoteName('ordering'))
                ->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
                ->where($db->quoteName('user_id') . ' = :userid')
                ->bind(':userid', $userId, ParameterType::INTEGER);
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $usedOrdering = $db->loadColumn();

            $order = 1;
            $query->clear()
                ->insert($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'));

            foreach ($data['customprofile'] as $k => $v) {
                while (in_array($order, $usedOrdering)) {
                    $order++;
                }

                $query->values(
                    implode(
                        ',',
                        $query->bindArray(
                            [
                                $userId,
                                'customprofile.' . $k,
                                json_encode($v),
                                $order++,
                            ],
                            [
                                ParameterType::INTEGER,
                                ParameterType::STRING,
                                ParameterType::STRING,
                                ParameterType::INTEGER,
                            ]
                        )
                    )
                );
            }

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->execute();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove all user customprofile information for the given user ID
     *
     * Method is called after user data is deleted from the database
     *
     * @param   array    $user     Holds the user data
     * @param   boolean  $success  True if user was successfully stored in the database
     * @param   string   $msg      Message
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    public function onUserAfterDelete($user, $success, $msg): void
    {
        if (!$success) {
            return;
        }

        $userId = ArrayHelper::getValue($user, 'id', 0, 'int');

        if ($userId) {
            $db = $this->db;
            $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->delete($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'))
                ->where($db->quoteName('user_id') . ' = :userid')
                ->where($db->quoteName('profile_key') . ' LIKE ' . $db->quote('customprofile.%'))
                ->bind(':userid', $userId, ParameterType::INTEGER);

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $db->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it, thank you!